# Proving a Complex Inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Take $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C},$ and assume $|z_1| < 1, |z_2| < 1.$ I want to
prove that
$$\left|\frac{z_1-z_2}{1-\bar{z}_1z_2}\right| < 1.$$
Take $z_1 = x+iy, z_2 = a+ib$ for $x,y,a,b \in \mathbb{R}.$ We see that
$$|z_1| < 1 \implies \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 1 \implies x^2 + y^2 < 1.$$
similarly we see that
$$|z_2| < 1 \implies \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} < 1 \implies a^2 + b^2 < 1.$$
We see that
$$\left|\frac{z_1-z_2}{1-\bar{z}_1z_2}\right|
 =\left|\frac{(x-a) + i(y-b)}{1 -(x-iy)(a+ib)}\right|
 =\left|\frac{(x-a) + i(y-b)}{1 -(xa + ibx -iay + yb)}\right|
 =\left|\frac{(x-a) + i(y-b)}{(1-xa-yb) + i(ay - bx)}\right|.$$
However, I am beginning to have some issues as to how to simplify this to a
non-fraction. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling with complex numbers directly would be much easier. 
Take the square on both side of the desired inequality and use the formula
$$
|z|^2=z\bar z.
$$

Eventually, you end up with
$$
|a|^2+|b|^2-\bar ab-a\bar b<1-\bar ab-a\bar b-|a|^2|b|^2.
$$
Now use the assumption $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$.

The transformation in your question is called [Blaschke Factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlaschkeFactor.html).